# Can not get the navigation menu to render inside of a div

Tags: jquery, css, html

I can not for the life of me get this navigation menu to sit within a div I need it in a div so that I can style the background of the menu to match my site here is a jsfiddle of the menu and div. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/gWxp8/4/

```
iv.mydiv
{
    background-color:#CE04E3;
}
.menu, .menu ul {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     position: relative;
     line-height: 2.5em;
 }
 .menu a {
     text-decoration: none;
 }
 .menu > li {
     margin-left: 15px;
 }
 .menu > li:first {
 margin-left:0px!important;
 }
 .menu > li > a {
     padding: 0px 10px;
     margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #838383;
 font-weight: bold;
 }
   div.box {
     position: absolute;
     z-index: -1;
     background-color: #75CDD2;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
     border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
 }
 li.pull-down {
     padding-right:6px;
 }
 li.pull-down > a {
     background-image: url('../images/darrow.png');
     background-position: 96% 75%;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     padding-right: 20px;
 }
 li.right-menu > a {
     background-image: url('../images/rarrow.png');
     background-position: 97% 45%;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
 .menu a.selected {
     background-color: #75CDD2;
     border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 4px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 4px;
 }
 .menu li {
     float: left;
     position: relative;
 }
 .menu ul {
     position: absolute;
     display: none;
     width: 200px;
     top: 2.5em;
     /*padding-right: 10px;*/
     background-color: #75CDD2;
     /*-moz-opacity: .50;     filter: alpha(opacity=50);     opacity: .50;*/
 border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 4px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 4px;
 }
 .menu li ul a {
     width: 180px;
     height: auto;
     float: left;
     color: #FFFEFD;
     padding: 0 10px;
 }
 .menu li ul li {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 }
 .menu ul ul {
 top: auto;
 }
 .menu li ul ul {
 left: 198px;
     /*margin: 0px 0 0 10px;*/
 }
 .menu-item-selected > a {
 background-color: #FFFEFD;
     -moz-opacity: .50;
     filter: alpha(opacity=50);
     opacity: .50;
 }
 .menu-item-selected > a:hover {
     color: #257E84 !important;
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing your FLOATS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `<li>` elements are floated left, they are removed from the document flow.
So the `<ul>` has no height, doesn't expand its container's height, and appears below its container.

Try clearing the floats after your `<ul>` element like this:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

(There are [other methods of clearing floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html), as seen in other answers here -- this is just an example.)

http://jsfiddle.net/gWxp8/8/

Answer (score 2):

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gWxp8/9/)

Add this code to the `div.mydiv` class:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: Updated fiddle, as the linked one doesn't contain this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/gWxp8/9/

Answer (score 1):

You're using floats, which screw with everything!

Changing the `li` CSS to `display:inline-block;` fixes it.

[updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gWxp8/7/)

Comment: This worked perfectly! The only issue I am having now is the menu items appear behind the page content, would you happen to know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `overflow: hidden` to the menu `ul` because you are using floating elements inside it.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gWxp8/6/)

```
ul.menu {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of clearfix on div.myDiv.  See this for all the info: [What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

Answer (score 0):

Add following CSS

```
.menu {
        display: inline-block;
    }
```